# Animate a Chat Head

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I am developing an app to show chat head.
I have to implement translate animation on chat head, but it is not animating.

```
TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2, 0, 
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
trans.setFillAfter(false);
trans.setDuration(1000);
view.setAnimation(trans);

trans.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: you haven't `startAnimation` yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [start animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)) on view:

```
view.startAnimation(trans);
```

Comment: I have used Start Animation.That chat head need to move at top of screen,using translate.

Comment: According to your code, you used setAnimation method.

Comment: Try setting fill after to true

Comment: I also used set Filter.That animation code is running well when i make another project,but not working on chat head(Floating window on all apps).I need same as like link bubble app have.

Comment: Are you sure "chat head" is visible and positioned on top of other views?